# How can I send a different ID as a parameter for a JS function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to send an id to a function but I don't know how to do it. I have a my function like this

```
    function showHide(item) {
        if (document.getElementById('item.id').style.display=='none') {
            document.getElementBydId('item.id').style.display = '';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('item.id').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

and my HTML like this

```
    <div onclick="showHide(one);">
        <img src="images/1.png">
    </div>
    <div id="one" style="display:none">
        <h1>X List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Elmt 1</li>
            <li>Elmt 2</li>
            <li>Elmt 3</li>
            <li>Elmt 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But, I have more divs with diferent id's, so I don't want to create more functions for each id. How can I send the "one, two, three,..." id to another onclick div?

Comment: You're quoting where you shouldn't and not quoting where you should.

Comment: You have `'item.id'`, but it should be `item.id` -- but how about just `document.getElementById(item)` and `showHide("one")`.

Comment: @Abdel don't forget to accept the answer you like the most. It will give you reputation and people will always answer on your questions. If you don't and they see in your profile they might stop.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="visibility" id="one">
        <img src="images/1.png">
  </div>
  <div id="match-one">
        <h1>X List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Elmt 1</li>
            <li>Elmt 2</li>
            <li>Elmt 3</li>
            <li>Elmt 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
     var hasClass = function (ele, cls) {
        return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
     },
     removeClass = function (ele, cls) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
        ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, ' ');
     },
     showHide = function (item) {
      var element = document.getElementById('match-' + this.id);
          if(hasClass(element, 'hide')) {
              removeClass(element, 'hide');
          } else {
              element.className = element.className + 'hide';
          }
      },
      cell = document.querySelectorAll('.visibility'),
      i;
    for(i = cell.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cell[i].addEventListener('click', showHide, false);
    }
}());
```

css:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

I chose this solution because is very scalable and it doesn't override css

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div onclick="showHide('one');">
function showHide(item) {
    var el = document.getElementById(item);
    if (el.style.display === 'none') {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're quoting in wrong place and You have a typo in 3rd line. Change Your code on this:

JavaScript:

```
function showHide(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display=='none') {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div onclick="showHide('one');">
```

And, for the record, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library. It is very useful and easier than using only JavaScript. Thanks to it, Your JavaScript code would look like this:

```
function showHide(id) {
    if ($('#'+id).is(':hidden')) {
        $('#'+id).show();
    }
    else {
        $('#'+id).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. Saw it a minute ago ^^. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Some syntax edits to your code, this ShowHide function should work with any ID you pass it. Just be sure you pass the ID as a string

```
<div onclick="showHide('one');"> // Added quotes here
<img src="images/1.png" />
</div>

<div id="one" style="display:none">
    <h1>X List</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Elmt 1</li>
        <li>Elmt 2</li>
        <li>Elmt 3</li>
        <li>Elmt 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>


function showHide(item) {
    if (document.getElementById(item).style.display=='none') { // Use the ID (a string) to get the element
        document.getElementBydId(item).style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(item).style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you had also some typos like `BydId`... try this http://jsfiddle.net/nphLvn3j/

```
function showHide(item) {

    if (document.getElementById(item).style.display=='none') {
        document.getElementById(item).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(item).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG the "D" was the problem, but also the quoting. Thank you

Comment: @AbdelPosada your welcome, all the others also didn't see it :)